# AngularJs - Route by exact match only is possible?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-route-segment

In my app, I would like to match the `url` exactly. in case the `url` doesn't match exactly, I require to redirect to defualt as '`.

at present I require to test:

`localhost:3000/sn=1234 or localhost:3000/sn=abc123 or localhost:3000/sn=abc123`

that means, minimum the `sn=` should presence with `values` whether by number or alphabets or both mixed.

at present my `state` looks like this:

```
.state('serialCreateCase', {
        url: '^/sn={serialNumber}',
        templateUrl:'app/createCase/create-case.html',
        controller: 'createCaseController as ctrl'

      })
```

But it works for : both `localhost:3000/sn=, localhost:300/sn` - how to prevent this? and match the required value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression qualifier for the state parameter. For example

```
url: '/sn={serialNumber:[a-z0-9]+}'
```

See https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher

**Note:** I removed the `^` prefix you had on your URL. No documentation I've seen supports such a format.